# Spaces between texts in listview android

Tags: android, listview, layout

I have 3 TextViews in my ListView rows.
I want to space them equally. I tried working with gravity, but it isn't working.
The spaces provided should be equally distributed among the texts or can vary.

Below is the code:

list.xml

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="457dp"
    android:id="@+id/payment_plan_list_view"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"

    />
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
            android:id="@+id/sr_no"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
            android:id="@+id/stage"
            android:layout_weight="3"

            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
            android:id="@+id/percentage"
            android:layout_weight="3"

            />
    </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
            android:id="@+id/sr_no"
            android:layout_weight="0.35"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:padding="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
            android:id="@+id/stage"
            android:layout_weight="0.35"

            android:singleLine="true"
            android:padding="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
            android:id="@+id/percentage"
            android:layout_weight="0.30"

            android:singleLine="true"
            android:padding="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: Nothing is getting displayed

Answer (score 1):

Remove the TableLayout, and simply use **weights**.
The weighted dimension must be **0dp**, to work.
Also note that my LinearLayout has an **horizontal** orientation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center"
        android:id="@+id/sr_no"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center"
        android:id="@+id/stage"
    />  
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center"
        android:id="@+id/percentage"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: By using just weights and no table layout the text views are getting displayed below one another.

Comment: Change your LinearLayout orientation to horizontal.

Comment: `the text views are getting displayed below one another` Because you specified a **vertical** orientation. My LinearLayout is **horizontal**.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the gravity Left/Center it's obvious that they will be like.

1

2

3

If you want the textview to be like 1-2-3, use padding and weight and remove gravity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/sr_no"
/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/stage"
/>  
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:text="New Text
    android:id="@+id/percentage"
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to   `android:layout_width="0dp"`

And then set `android:layout_weight="3"` to `android:layout_weight="1"`

And as above comment says, remove `TableLayout` - not sure of its purpose.